# Usage of Woocommerce's template system

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, templating

I am trying to use Woocommerce's wc_get_template function to load my own templates, but it dosen't seem to work (it's not outputting content from the template files), together with my Woocommerce plugin. Below is what I have tried:

plugindir/templates/testing-template.php:

```
<h1>Output stuff</h1>
```

plugindir/pluginname.php:

```
if(in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {

    function template_loader(){
      wc_get_template('testing-template.php', array());
    }

    add_action('init', 'template_loader');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`wc_get_template` will first try to load the template from the the theme in the woocommerce folder. If it does not find the template in the theme's woocommerce folder it will try and load the template from woocommerce templates folder.

`wc_get_tempalte` will not just work with any template you want.  If you are building a plugin of your own you can try and look at the `WC_Template` Class and try to mitigate the functionality of `wc_template` in your own plugin with `plugin_prefix_template()` and also have a templates folder in your plugin.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Template_Loader.html#13-510